# Announcer no longer announces every kill

Tags: league-of-legends

I believe this started with Patch 5.22 for the preseason.  The announcer no longer gives audio for every single kill like it used to. It still calls multi-kills, and an unknown pattern for other individual kills.  Is there a setting or something to re-enable this? I like the audio cue to know how many champions are still alive, particularly in large teamfights where it can be hard to keep track of which particles mean something is dead or not.

Comment: 5.22 patch notes do not designate any changes to the announcer, and I cannot find anyone else mentioning similar problems. i have had a delay in announcement when multiple kills were made or when turret kills and champion kills happened at the same time. it may be a bug. you can try contacting customer support.

Comment: Same here. I've experiences delays but I've not been paying attention enough to notice that the announcer missed to broadcast a kill.

Comment: The visual cue is still there, just not audio

Comment: As mentioned before, this wasn't documented anywhere. Try using the repair function in the game patcher and see if that helps. If not, it's probably an unintended bug and you should mention it on the boards.

Comment: I have experienced this (in ARAM). It doesn't even always call out the multi-kills and shutdowns, and also when there no kills for > 30 seconds before or after a kill. I think I have experienced this in most if not all ARAM games I've played since 5.22

Comment: The announcer sometimes mixes things up for me. If an enemy got a triple kill she tends to say triple kill first and then double kill for some reason.

Comment: For me there can be a major delay but all or most of the kills will eventually be announced. I mostly noticed this on ARAM and I think it is a result of the sound bites queueing up for all of the kills in rapid succession.

Answer (score 1):

According to my researches (which came up empty) i would assume that somewhere in the game code they must've made so the sounds don't overlap (so you won't hear double and triple kill at the same time) and i guess (again sorry for not being sure of anything, these are assumptions and speculations, but i couldn't find anything online) that if a certain time passes they no longer play the audio since it's pointless by then.

Again, do not take anything i said has a certainty ***this is all speculation on my part*** , for which i am posting to try and give some possible reasons has to why this happens (again, not sure on anything!!)

This question is something either a **Riot Staff** or a person who know's or has access to the actual game code (Or someone who knows someone there, you get where i'm headed don't you?) to be able to specify the reason, it might even be an actual bug in the game that Riot themselves haven't noticed, or have but haven't made any impactfull changes to fix it since it doesn't affect the actual gameplasy (What's wrong with missing the announcemment on a kill or two? You can still see the kill feed and score).

What i'm trying to say is, all we can do is wait until Riot either fix this, or just cry about the announcer not saying Pentakill when you are playing Full Ap Amumu (It works some games!)

Comment: League's announcer sounds haven't been able to overlap since I started playing over 2 years ago, so this doesn't seem correct.

Comment: I'm not saying it is correct, just giving some thoughts of what i think might be the reason has to why the announcer doesn't announce everything

Comment: I think it might be a change to make it so that announcements don't go on forever when a bunch of announcements get queued up at once. I'm not sure what the priority is, but if someone gets a triple and there's a double ace and the minions take a tower, you'll get two ace messages, a triple message, and a tower down message, but none of the single kill announcements. Like I said, I don't know the priority (or if this is even how it works) but anecdotally, I feel like this is the case.

Comment: Well for all we know, that is how it works, only Riot Staff and people that have access to the actual code and such will know

Comment: Actually, not even a Riot Staff may know **exactly** how it works.  The current version is most likely the end result of a series of bug fixes, and unless someone decided to document exactly how the announcer fixes were done (unlikely), nobody will know exactly how this works unless they go spend hours and reverse engineer all the code.  From observation, we just know that it doesn't overlap, and does not play all the queued sounds, so somewhere there is logic that drops announcements to make it less annoying.